# Symmetric but not so good looking arctan sum

Tags: inverse-function, symmetric-polynomials

If
$a, b, c$ are real positive numbers and

$\theta=\tan ^{-1}\left[\frac{a(a+b+c)}{b c}\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}+\tan ^{-1}\left[\frac{b(a+b+c)}{c a}\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}+
\tan ^{-1}\left[\frac{c(a+b+c)}{a b}\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}$

then $\tan \theta$ equals?

---

I did this by adding the arctan terms twice, It took a lot of time and a ton of trials and error. I don't even want to type the solution in TeX

I know this is a symmetric equation,
which are usually easy to solve (Still learning that) but I'm not able to simplify it. How can I solve it in a more simple way?

(And help me with the tags too)

Answer (score 3):

It would be nice to first the  simplify the argument of $\tan^{-1}$

Let $ \dfrac{a+b+c}{abc}=s^2$ so the sum *looks* simple
$$\theta=  \tan ^{-1}(as )+\tan ^{-1}(bs) +\tan ^{-1}(cs )$$

Now you can do the same, or simply use the identity:

If $x_1,x_2 \ldots x_n$ are real then
$$\tan ^{-1} x_{1}+\tan ^{-1} x_{2}+\ldots+\tan ^{-1} x_{n}=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{S_{1}-S_{3}+S_{5}-S_{7}+\ldots}{1-S_{2}+S_{4}-S_{6}+\ldots}\right)$$
Where $S_{k}$ denotes the sum of products of $x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots x_{n}$ taken $k$ at a time.

And in this equation, $ \displaystyle \sum_{cyc} \tan^{-1}(s\cdot a_i) $

$$\theta = \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{(as+bs+cs) - (abcs^3)}{1-(a bs^{2}+bcs^{2}+a cas^{2})} \right) \\ =  \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{s\left((a+b+c)-a b c s^{2}\right)}{1-s^2(ab+b c+a c)}\right)$$

See that $ \left( a+b+c - abc \cdot s^2 \right) = 0$

Thus, $\tan (\theta) = 0$

Comment: Okay,  first of all, how did you type all that so quickly ? And second, how did you know what to substitute?

Comment: Remember  $$\sqrt{a}\ge0$$  for real positive $a$

Comment: @Ashley, I use a LaTeX editor, which is helpful in typing long equations. And .. well, you see the common thing in all the terms.. it comes with practice